# while passing same date in stored procedure data is not getting

Tags: sql-server

i have a table like this:
[image]

i have stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test4]    
  @startdate varchar(100),   
  @enddate varchar(100)
as  begin   
   declare @date1 datetime = CONVERT(datetime, @startdate + ' 00:01:00', 120);
   declare @date2 datetime = CONVERT(datetime, @enddate + ' 00:23:59', 120);

   select t.PlateNo  
   from Transaction_tbl t    
   WHERE dtime between @date1 AND @date2; 
end;
```

if i pass same date (start date:2013-05-07 and end date :2013-05-07) am not getting any result,,i am getting result if i pass differnet date only,,what is wrong with my stored procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Times are in hh:mm:ss

I think you need this:

declare @date1 datetime = CONVERT(datetime, @startdate + ' 00:00:00', 120);
   declare @date2 datetime = CONVERT(datetime, @enddate + ' 23:59:59', 120);

Comment: sir ,,thats why i am setting starting date as 00:01:00 and ending date as end of the day time( i mean 00:23:59)

Comment: But that's just 23 minutes, 59 seconds into the day. And your times are all more than 17 hours.

Comment: oh,,by mistake i given date like that,,i given date like this:23:23:59.000 now am getting proper answer..thank for your help